# Springboot: Type definition error when posting a new object using a REST service

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have an object which gets a parameter through a json POST request to create a new entry in the database and I get this error:

> "Type definition error: [simple type, class
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]; nested exception is
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
> construct instance of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` (no
> Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need
> to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain
> additional type information\n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line:
> 1, column: 1]

The request from the POST request

```
    {
        "email": "user@gmail.com"
    }
```

this is the controller

```
 @PostMapping("/forgot_password")
public ResponseEntity<?> processForgotPassword(@RequestBody HttpServletRequest request, Model model, User user) {
    String email = (String) request.getAttribute(user.getEmail());
    String token = RandomString.make(30);

    try {
        userService.updateResetPasswordToken(token, email);
        String resetPasswordLink = Utility.getSiteURL(request) + "/reset_password?token=" + token;
        sendEmail(email, resetPasswordLink);
        model.addAttribute("message", "We have sent a reset password link to your email. Please check.");

    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException ex) {
        model.addAttribute("error", ex.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MessagingException e) {
        model.addAttribute("error", "Error while sending email");
    }

    return ResponseEntity.ok("Reset link sent Successfully");
}
```

The service

```
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    public void updateResetPasswordToken(String token, String email) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (user != null) {
            user.setResetPasswordToken(token);
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("Could not find any user with the email " + email);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to remove the @RequestBody

Comment: Note that you should _almost never_ actually manipulate `HttpServletR*`; Spring handles all of the nasty plumbing for you. In your case, you should probably be using `@ModelAttribute String email`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example](https://github.com/khoubyari/spring-boot-rest-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/khoubyari/example/api/rest/HotelController.java), `HttpServletRequest` is injected with the `@RequestBody` not needed, so just remove that annotation.

```java
@PostMapping("/forgot_password")
public ResponseEntity<?> processForgotPassword(HttpServletRequest request) {
  // do something
{
```

The `@RequestBody` represents build an object from the body of the HTTP request, but `HttpServletRequest` is the whole HTTP request. It's the mismatch that leads to the error.

Comment: the error is gone, but when I send the request, the message is null `{
  "timestamp": "2021-01-09T05:45:02.475+00:00",
  "message": null,
  "details": "uri=/api/user/forgot_password"
}`

Comment: The current response is spring's default behavior. You should define your response format properly. Nowadays we usually use [@RestController](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller) to make the response format controlled. If you have further questions, feel free to create a new one. Remember to mark this question as resolved if the answer solves your problem.

Comment: cant upvote less points, required 15 am at 11

Comment: I'm not familiar with spring mvc things, the response format problem need more research.

Comment: You still can mark it as resolved, upvote is another unique operation.